# Copy/Paste Cell with Certain Color VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to VBA.

On each sheet, I'm trying to copy the cell which fits the RGB profile and paste it in T2 of the same sheet.

Module is running but nothing is happening.

Thanks in advance

```
    Sub CopyColor()

    Dim rCell As Range

       For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
          If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
          rCell.Select
          rCell.Copy
          rCell("T2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

       End If
     Next rCell

    End Sub
```

Update: Oops, I meant to PasteValues. Got it to run on the active sheet, but I need it to go through the whole workbook. Tried this modification and it didn't work:

```
    Sub CopyColor()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim wk As Worksheet

       For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

          For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
             If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
                rCell.Copy
                Range("T2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
             End If
          Next rCell
      Next wk

    End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each rCell in wk.UsedRange`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Sub CopyColor()

Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
        rCell.Copy
        Range("T2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Another possiblity:

```
Sub CopyColor()

Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then Range("T2").Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71)
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked to move the data (thanks!), but only for active sheet. See clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems with your code:

- `ColorIndex` is a color **Index**, as opposed by an RGB value
- `rCell.Select` does not do anything
- `rCell("T2")` does not mean anything to me, should be `Range(...)`

So a corrected version could be:

```
Sub CopyColor()
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
            rCell.Copy
            Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: This works but only on active sheet. I'm trying to add a ForEach line to run the module on the entire worksheet, but I'm not getting something right. See my edit to the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamBot - maybe you missed my comment on your question - if you're looping through `Each wk`, you then need to loop `For Each rCell In wk.UsedRange`..., not the `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @BigBen I tried making that change but I'm getting an object variable not defined message. Is there another change I need to make for 'For Each rCell In wk.UsedRange' to work?

Comment: @JamBot nested `For Each` should work, it's definitely that line that throws the object variable not set error? Also, you do realize that you haven't specified which sheet `Range("T2")` is on, so it is implicitly the `ActiveSheet` - and you'll overwrite the value in T2 every time a color match is found?

Comment: @bigben I added `wk.activate` below `For Each` and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or @JamBot you could avoid `Activate` and do `wk.Range("T2")` - which is cleaner and simpler.